# Right to Left text in a TextView

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, right-to-left

I have this string in strings.xml:

```
<string name="mystring">אב</string>
```

when I set the "text" propety of a `TextView` to this string, what I see in the Graphical Layout is this: "בא". (the opposite direction).
I have tried using the Unicode 'RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK'(U+200F), but it doesn't work. I still get "בא" instead of "אב".

Any ideas?

Comment: Java Approach String reverseString = new StringBuffer("abc").reverse().toString(); 
            System.out.println(".............."+reverseString);

Comment: Ah I missunderstood you need to actually write the text in reverse order?

Comment: Yes and no. "אב" is the value of the string. I don't want the TextView to look like "בא", but that is how it looks. If I revert the text, I also get reverse rows. I mean, if two lines are needed the last line will come before the first.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `TextView` to have `gravity=right` this should control the orientation of the contents of the view so it aligns to the right side.

Then reverse the order of the string so it reads right to left. You can use an approach similar to [this to reverse the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512718/customized-string-reverse-java) where you iterate over the string and just append the characters together in reverse order.

Then when you set your text it will be alligned to the right and read right to left.

Comment: I have already done that. It makes the text "stick" to the right, but the letters are still in the wrong order.

Comment: I linked to the code to reverse the order. You don't just need to pin the text to the right but also reverse the string.